# Why I cannot return this `Option<>`?

Tags: rust

Given the code in [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5b1456e892d2fad90fe680a71bc6bc26) is there a way to fix the error:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.coach` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:20:9
   |
20 |         self.coach
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `self.coach` has type `Option<Box<Coach>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
```

```rust
// #[derive(Default, Clone)]
pub struct Coach {
    pub id: Option<i64>,
    pub name: String,
    pub team: Option<Box<Coach>>,
}

// #[derive(Default, Clone)]
pub struct Team {
    pub id: Option<i64>,
    pub name: String,
    coach: Option<Box<Coach>>,
}

impl Team {
    pub fn coach(&self) -> Option<Box<Coach>> {
        self.coach
    }
}

pub struct RestCoach {
    pub id: i64,
    pub name: String,
}

impl From<Coach> for RestCoach {
    fn from(coach: Coach) -> Self {
        Self {
            id: coach.id.unwrap(),
            name: coach.name,
        }
    }
}

pub struct RestTeam {
    pub id: i64,
    pub name: String,
    pub coach: Option<RestCoach>,
}

impl From<Team> for RestTeam {
    fn from(team: Team) -> Self {
        Self {
            id: team.id.unwrap(),
            name: team.name.clone(),
            coach: team.coach().map(|x| RestCoach::from(*x)),
        }
    }
}
```

Is using `clone()` the only fix?

Answer (score 3):

First, when you return `Option<T>` you are handing ownership of the `T` to the caller.  When someone calls `team.coach()` do you want to transfer ownership of the coach to the caller and leave the team coachless? Or do you want to give them a reference to the coach?

It's better if the signature is `pub fn coach(&self) -> Option<&Coach>`. Let the caller borrow the coach, but have the team retain ownership. Also get rid of the `Box`. It's not relevant to the caller.

Second, `coach: Option<Box<Coach>>` means that teams *own* their coaches. I don't think that's the right way to model it. Coaches ought to exist outside of any one team. There are a couple of better ways to model it.

##### Shared references

Teams could have shared references to coaches. Coaches would need to be owned by some other piece of code. For example, in `main()` you could have a `Vec<Coach>` and a `Vec<Team>`. `main()` would own both the coaches and the teams, and the teams would merely have references to the coaches without taking ownership of them.

This requires the use of lifetimes. It has zero runtime overhead but it can mean tangling with the borrow checker, which isn't always fun.

```
pub struct Team<'coach> {
    pub id: Option<i64>,
    pub name: String,
    coach: Option<&'coach Coach>,
}

impl Team<'_> {
    pub fn coach(&self) -> Option<&Coach> {
        self.coach
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=179fd65dde71c0e833e970a514e88bb4)

##### Shared ownership

Teams could shared ownership of coaches with other teams by using, say, `Rc` or `Arc`. No one team would own a coach. This would make sense if a coach could coach multiple teams.

From a coding perspective this is nice because it gets rid of the lifetimes and gets the borrow checker out of your hair, though it does have some minor runtime overhead.

```
pub struct Team {
    pub id: Option<i64>,
    pub name: String,
    coach: Option<Rc<Coach>>,
}

impl Team {
    pub fn coach(&self) -> Option<&Coach> {
        self.coach.as_deref()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1db2b24845d325e9a0a38ef6911d8f60)

##### Weak references

Another approach would be to have teams keep `Weak` references to their coaches. Instead of the teams owning the `Rc<Coach>` shared pointers you'd have them stored somewhere else outside of the teams. Teams would effectively just have references to the `Rc` pointers.

They're "weak" references because they don't keep the coaches alive. Some other piece of code would have to own the `Rc` pointers and keep them alive. This means that the coaches could be dropped at any time independent of any team they're associated with. Team code would have to anticipate the possibility of the weak reference going stale.

```
pub struct Team {
    pub id: Option<i64>,
    pub name: String,
    coach: Option<Weak<Coach>>,
}

impl Team {
    pub fn coach(&self) -> Option<Rc<Coach>> {
        self.coach.as_ref().and_then(Weak::upgrade)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a740e4e376bc7895ef8f5d450912256a)

---

You'll need to apply a similar thought process to the rest of the program. `team: Option<Box<Coach>>` needs a similar rethink. Do coaches *own* teams? Probably not. Coaches work for teams, they don't own them.

Comment: Wow. I read your answer without breathing. Now I'm studying it better. What do you advise me to do for a program that reads from DB, unmarshal in these structs, does some little business logic, perhaps writes to the DB and responds in output to the caller? Tipical CRUD (with some little variations)?

Comment: There are many small decisions you'll have to make that I can't address at a 10,000-foot view. Rust really requires you to dig into the specifics. There isn't really a general "how to make CRUD apps" guide. Every application is different. For bigger picture advice I suggest posting on the [Rust Users Forum](https://users.rust-lang.org). They're better equipped to handle that kind of question.

Comment: Thank you. Anyway my original code with your `shared references` example still doesn't work: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3f651c240e5489e9c36aba726306a0c1.

Comment: See the last paragraph. You'll need to apply similar decision making to `team: Option<Box<Coach>>`. Do coaches own teams? Probably not.

Comment: I'm trying to use some of them in my real code on my PC and using `Rc` or `Weak` throws with `future cannot be sent between threads safely. Within \`Player\`, the trait \`std::marker::Send\` is not implemented for \`std::rc::Weak<Player>\``. Should I use `Arc` or `sync::Weak`, right?

Comment: Can you please better explain the differences between `Shared ownership` and `Weak references`?